# How do i read httponly cookies with webview_flutter package, or intercept all the response with it?

Tags: android, flutter, webview

i'm developing a flutter app with [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/) package and have several problem with the cookies. I want to get httponly cookie with it, then proces the cookie inside my flutter app. But, because the cookie is http only, i can't get that. So, how to get the cookie via my webview? or can i listen what is in the header of my current url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to read HTTP Only cookie from evaluate JavaScript, the only way to read the cookie is manually hit the API(ex: login) then save the cookie inside a global state or save it locally to your local storage.

Case solved.